# Regex que solo acepte numeros y guion medio en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, regex

tengo un problema que me pide que tal atributo solo acepte números y guion medio (para validar `phonenumber`).

Para `regex` soy nulo así que agradecería su ayuda.

Lo he intentado con esto pero no funciona:

```
`/^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto te validará todos los números y guiones `[0-9-]+$`

Si quisieras también limitar la longitud y el formato del nº de teléfono:

- Como el siguiente: `666-99-88-77` la expresión regular sería la siguiente `^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$`
- O como este otro: `666-998-877` la expresión regular sería la siguiente `^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}$`
- O cualquier formato tipo número/guión limitando únicamente la longitud entre 9 y 12: `[0-9-]{9,12}$`

Puedes comprobar el funcionamiento de cualquiera de estas expresiones regulares y ver el significado de cada expresión desde la siguiente herramienta online: https://regex101.com

Comment: Para lo requerido me fue suficiente con el primer regex `[0-9-]+$` muchas gracias